# What is the quickest way to see, document, and reproduce modification to the default build?

Tags: deployment

Long-term I would like to setup a more robust method of monitoring changes, doing backups, and doing incremental and complete recoveries & rollbacks - though right now, I am just looking to know:

**What is the quickest way to be able to create a baseline to make sure that it is easy to see, document, and if necessary manually reproduce (or remove) any modification that have made by users or me to the default build?**

** Please note that this request excludes any data that is accessible via DataLoader.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

- **Q:** "Are you talking about changes to Custom Object, Fields, Layouts etc?"
- **A:** Yes, though to be more exact, I am referencing anything that is not accessible via DataLoader. Guessing there are configs that are
  more likely to be of significance, though I have a very limited
  knowledge of either what those might be, or for that matter what
  might be required to digest & reproduce any changes discovered. For
  example, even it it is possible to download a meaningful amount of
  config files via the Force IDE, using those files to understanding
  what changes were made and how to manually reproduce them would I am
  guessing be challenging, if not impossible.

Comment: Are you talking about changes to Custom Object, Fields, Layouts etc?

Comment: **@AndrewFawcett:** Updated the body of the question in an attempt to address your question. If I am able to provide any additional information, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have Enterprise Edition or higher...
You need to look into Git backups. Git allows you to create a backup and every time changes are made (if they are made) the changes are recorded and even highlighted.

You will need to do the following;

1. Sign up to a free AND private bitbucket account (https://bitbucket.org)
2. Install [Copado Deployer](http://www.copa.do) from the AppExchange (can be used for free) - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3dgGEAR
3. Create the Org credentials in the app (instructions here: http://www.copa.do/cms/documentation#createOrg)
4. Add your Git repository to Copado (instructions here: http://www.copa.do/cms/documentation#gitRepository)
5. Set the git backup (instructions here: http://www.copa.do/cms/documentation#gitBackup)

---

**UPDATE:**
I believe my reply answers your question. Let me clarify... you would like a robust method to: 1) monitor changes 2) do backups (metadata) 3) doing incremental and complete recoveries & rollbacks (metadata)

I have added metadata in brackets because doing this for data would be tricky for various reasons (e.g. deletions + related data). Also since you've done research on the backup topic

Git versioning allows you to monitor changes. Here is a link to an example output that Git produces: bit.ly/1kIT0jn

Using Git Backups you would get such an output to see exactly what has changed. I hope this addresses point 1 and 2.

Regarding point 3: For now you're right this is a manual/complicated process. If I find any solution that handles a backup process for metadata well and in a more automated way (push/pull), I'll let you know. If anyone knows more extensive solutions, I'd be interested to hear of these.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: +1 Interesting, and yes, the account is the Enterprise Edition. How do you suggest I estimate how many "credits" would be required to to a "full" backup and recovery (meaning recovery as much as Copado is able to do). And yes, I get that the system does much more than this, but the base line is how much the "full" push/pull for a complete backup & recovery would be. Again, thanks; I've done a lot of research and either missed Copado, or never ran across it.

Comment: Given you've flawed to reply to my question in the comment above, I've decided not to spend anytime reviewing your answer, but have selected it as the answer. If you're willing to answer the question in the comment above, I'll review the product; if it seems it won't cost and arm & leg to do a full backup & recovery.

Comment: Looking at the copado website (http://www.copa.do/cms/pricing) you could do 10 backups per month for free.
If you wanted this more regularly e.g. daily, the Developer subscription for €10/month would get you there.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll give it a try, the "[Credit Usage](http://www.copa.do/cms/documentation#creditUsage)" detail info from Copado is what is confusing me, though guess I'll give it a go. Main issue I see for sure is that it does not appear that Copado pull/push would automatically work for org-2-org data pull/push.

Comment: Hmm, so finally got around to looking at Copado and noticed Copado is your product; [Philipp Rackwitz, Founder and CEO](https://twitter.com/PhilippRackwitz) of [@CopadoSolutions](https://twitter.com/CopadoSolutions) -  is this correct? If so, please update your answer to disclose your affiliation (which is fine, as long as the answer is on topic and an answer) otherwise this just appears to you marketing a product.

Answer (score 0):

AutoRABIT has some of the core-capabilities of what you wish for . It is an end-end release management solution and has the best packaging and deployment solution which can be done right from your ALM Story like Jira or Rational Team Concert , from you Sandbox or from version control. You will get weekly or on-demand schedule reports of your Org Differences as well .
You can see more capabilities for [Salesforce Release Management](http://www.autorabit.com/blog/autorabit-for-salesforce-release-management-30-good-reasons/) here.